# jQuery not getting attribute value

Tags: javascript, jquery

jQuery:

```
$(".close_invoice").confirm({
    title: 'Are you sure to delete it?',
    content: 'Click to Delete if you are sure else click on Close.',
    type: 'red',
    typeAnimated: true,
    buttons: {
        delete: {
            text: 'Delete',
            btnClass: 'btn-red',
            action: function() {
                alert($(this).attr("id"));
            }
        },
        close: {
            text: 'Close',
            btnClass: 'btn-blue',
            action: function() {}
        }
    }
});
```

HTML:

```
<button class="btn btn-sm green btn-outline filter-submit margin-bottom close_invoice" id="14" jc-attached="true"><i class="fa fa-times"></i> Close Invoice</button>
```

Anyone can please tell me Why it not taking the value of attribute ID. How can I get the value of attribute ID? It alerting undefined.

Comment: Please try to trace what "this" object is inside the action function, with `console.log(this);`. Because it can be a scope problem. And please tell me what ".confirm()" function is, bootbox plugin?

Comment: `this` might be referencing to something else. Did you try debugging? Or can you post a snippet/fiddle?

Comment: you give `id="14"` in html but in js you have to call like this `alert($(this).attr("#14"));` .

Comment: @Tobia .confirm stand for plugin.

Answer (score 1):

You can't use `this` selector in `function object parameters`..You can save this `value` to a variable, then put it as `function paramater object's value`

Comment: I think you can use `this` in function obj parameter, it depends how this function parameter is called! In this case it depends on plugin function call implementation.